# DotNetOpenAuth authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

Does DotNetOpenAuth still redirect users to provider website i.e.( (OpenId) for authentication and authorisation from OAuth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - because that's how OpenID and OAuth work. There's no other way to do it.

Comment: Is it possible to be our own provider?

Comment: Sure - the code is in DotNetOpenAuth for that, but it kind of defeats the objection if you're going to limit logins to those from just your own provider.

Comment: It defeats it yes... unless you're in an organizational SSO environment where you control all the user accounts, and you want users to be implicitly signed into all RPs once they authentication to the IdP, using OpenID.